# For Python language, What is the difference between single and double quotation marks

Tags: python, formatting, apostrophe

While I am developing the Python code, I found I used to use single quotation marks all the time, but some experienced programmers used double quotation marks more often. I couldn't find the difference between them, could anyone help to give me some examples if there is a difference? Or is it just a personal preference?
For example:

```
class TextBox(UIControl):
    def draw(self):
    print('TextBox')

class TextBox2(UIControl):
    def draw(self):
        print("TextBox")
```

class TextBox and TextBox2 seems like have no difference while running.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Nothing but style](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings)

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that if you have a single quote in string, like can't, using a double quote prevents you from having to escape the single quote with a back slash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The uses of quotation marks and double quotation marks are the same, but you can use them in different cases; I'll give some examples as follows;

```
# Use of quotation mark ''
print('This is a "python code"')

# Use of double quotation mark ""
print("This is a 'python code'")

# More specific case (triple quotation mark)
print('''"This is a 'python code'"''')
```

If quotation mark is in a text to print, you should use double quotation mark.
If double quotation mark is in a text to print, you should use quotation mark.
If both of them is in a text to print, you should use triple quotation mark.

I'd be very happy if you let me know your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between them, except for the looks.
For example if you did:

```
print("Hello world")
```

It is the same as:

```
print('Hello world')
```

But I like to do the first one.